# Android Eclipse: Library reference in project properties VS Import statement

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Using a tutorial from a book i've built a game engine library using package structure advo.advoengine. I have several class files in there. In the following directory of my workspace are the following java files:

```
C:\Users\kevin\workspace\AdvoEngine\src\advo\advoengine
- Engine.java
- TextPrinter.java
```

etc

I then create another Android project using package structure advo.advoengine_demo. IN order to use the  library made above, Under Project Properties -> Android I specify the Advoengine as a library reference.

However in order to use TextPrinter class in my new Android project, I still need to specify

```
import advo.advoengine.*;
```

else TextPrinter cannot be resolved to a type.

Noob question but why do i still need to "import" the package when i've already specified the library reference?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> Noob question but why do i still need to "import" the package when i've already specified the library reference?

Because you always have to have an import for every Java class you refer to. The only exception is that other classes in the same package as the current class are automatically imported. This is standard Java behavior, having nothing to do with Android and library projects.